# Matlab: Names of the variables in a struct

Tags: matlab, struct

Given a struct from a function with a number of unknown fields, how do I get the name of each field?

For example:

```
s = struct;
s.hello = 'world';
s.foo = 12;
s.bar = [ 1 2 3 ];
```

I want the name of s(1), s(2) and s(3). In this case I would get 'hello', 'foo' and 'bar'.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're looking for [FIELDNAMES](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/fieldnames.html)

```
fieldnames(s)
fn = 
    'hello'
    'foo'
    'bar'
```

Note that `fn` is a cell array, so you get the `'foo'` as `fn{2}`

Comment: Sweet, exactly what I needed.